# Sorting array by size of split

Tags: perl, sorting

I am trying to sort an array by the size of the parts of its elements. The items follow a pattern `x/y[.../z]` and I want them sorted on the amount of items there are. E.g. `1/2` has two items after splitting on `/`, `12/365/85` has three. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong in such a seemingly simple snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @dummy_arr = ['12345/3/365/45/12', '1/2', '3/2', '1/2/3', '2/3/4'];
@dummy_arr = sort { scalar ( split /\//, $a ) < scalar ( split /\//, $b ) } @dummy_arr;

print Dumper(\@dummy_arr);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '12345/3/365/45/12',
            '1/2',
            '3/2',
            '1/2/3',
            '2/3/4'
          ]

        ];
```

Expected output:

```
$VAR1 = [
            '1/2',
            '3/2',
            '1/2/3',
            '2/3/4',
            '12345/3/365/45/12'
        ];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are mixing up a few things.

You put an array reference into your `@dummy_arr`.

> ```
> my @dummy_arr = [ '12345/3/365/45/12', '1/2', '3/2', '1/2/3', '2/3/4' ];
> ```

This is equal to:

```
my @dummy_arr =  ( [ '12345/3/365/45/12', '1/2', '3/2', '1/2/3', '2/3/4' ] );
```

In your `Dumper` output that's also visible.

```
$VAR1 = [                   # <-- because of the ref \@dummy_arr you pass to Dumper
          [                 # <-- first elem is already an array ref
            '12345/3/365/45/12',
            '1/2',
            '3/2',
            '1/2/3',
            '2/3/4'
          ]
        ];
```

So when you did `sort { ... } @dummy_arr`, there was only one value passed to `sort`. Because `sort` is smart, it skips, as there is nothing to sort if there is only `$a`, but no `$b`. This becomes obvious when you put a `{ warn $a; scalar ... }` into the `sort` lambda. There is no warning, so it never gets called.

But you're not sorting anyway. The [`sort` lambda](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) needs to return something similar to  `-1`, `0` or `1`.

> If SUBNAME is specified, it gives the name of a subroutine that
>   returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than 0 , depending
>   on how the elements of the list are to be ordered.

But you're using `<`, which only returns `1` or `0`. You need to use [`<=>` for numerical comparison](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators).

```
my @dummy_arr = ( '12345/3/365/45/12', '1/2', '3/2', '1/2/3', '2/3/4' );
@dummy_arr = sort { scalar( split /\//, $a ) <=> scalar( split /\//, $b ) } 
   @dummy_arr;

print Dumper( \@dummy_arr );

__END__
$VAR1 = [
          '1/2',
          '3/2',
          '1/2/3',
          '2/3/4',
          '12345/3/365/45/12'
        ];
```

---

Finally, because splitting is an expensive operation that needs to be repeated *a lot* if there are a lot of elements in the array, you might want to use [a *Schwartzian Transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) for this.

```
my @dummy_arr = ( '12345/3/365/45/12', '1/2', '3/2', '1/2/3', '2/3/4' );
@dummy_arr =
    map  { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map  { [ $_, scalar split( qr{/}, $_ ) ] } @dummy_arr;
```

This produces the same output, but trades memory for CPU, so it is way faster.

Comment: More precisely, the sort lambda should return < 0, 0,or > 0. Another approach would therefore be to replace `<` with `-`.

Comment: D'oh! Working with different languages all day makes me forget the syntactic differences between data types in different languages. Also +1 for the Schwartzian Transform, very interesting!